# Python3 Portscanner can't solve the socket pr0blem

Tags: python, sockets, port-scanning

When I run this code I am getting this socket error:

> [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

but even if I delete the `s.close()` it gives me wrong results.

It is a port scanner that are going to try connecting to all ports on the server I want to scan. And the ones that i'm getting connection from is stored in a list. But for some reason it is giving me wrong results. can someone please help me.

```
import socket
import threading

def scan_for_open_ports():
    #Creating variables
    OpenPorts = []
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = input('Host to scan: ')
    global port
    global OpenPorts
    port = 1
    #Scanning
    for i in range(65534):

        try:

            s.connect((host, port))
            s.shutdown(2)
            OpenPorts.append(port)
            print(str(port) + 'is open.')
            s.close()
            port += 1
        except socket.error as msg:
            print(msg)
            s.close()
    show_user()
def show_user():
    #Giving the user results
    print('------Open porst-----\n')
    print(OpenPorts)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're closing your socket inside the loop with `s.close()` and you're not opening it again and you try to connect with a socket that's closed already. you should close the socket when you're done with it at the end of the loop, i also amended your code to make `OpenPorts` global and remove the unnecessary `port` variable you define and increment inside your for loop

```
import socket

OpenPorts = []


def scan_for_open_ports():

    # Creating variables
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = input('Host to scan: ')

    # Scanning
    for port in range(1, 65534):
        try:
            s.connect((host, port))
            OpenPorts.append(port)
            print(str(port) + 'is open.')
        except socket.error as msg:
            print(msg)
    s.close()

    show_user()


def show_user():
    # Giving the user results
    print('------Open ports-----\n')
    print(OpenPorts)

scan_for_open_ports()
```

Comment: consider accepting my answer if it worked for you :)