# Scann WAN ports

Tags: python, sockets, security, networking, port

I've got a problem with a script for port scan at my virtual network[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECsM3.png) at virtualbox. I tried many scripts in python. I want to scann ,,WAN" port but the scripts are frozen at first port, what you can see at picture below[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeW04.png)( 192.168.3.101 is Kali Linux address). Do you know how can I fix it?
One of many scripts which i tried: [Python3 Portscanner can't solve the socket pr0blem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629530/python3-portscanner-cant-solve-the-socket-pr0blem)

I've got a network simulation in virtualbox:

[Network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECsM3.png)

[PfSenseLogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeW04.png)

Answer (score 1):

the problem was probably that pfsense was refusing to scan multiple ports from the same address in a short amount of time and I had to add delay after each port.